# libGDX - screen resizes after resuming the app

Tags: android, screen, libgdx, resolution, resume

I'm developing a 2D game in libGDX and I have a big problem with the resolution after resuming a screen.

After starting the app the screen looks like this:
[initial screen http://image-upload.de/image/uRVE3f/e8022a5f11.png](http://image-upload.de/image/uRVE3f/e8022a5f11.png)
Note that the graphics are scaled to fit the screen size.

After changing to another app and resuming the game the screen looks like this:
[resumed screen http://image-upload.de/image/syUI3u/7ff85232d1.png](http://image-upload.de/image/syUI3u/7ff85232d1.png)
Note that the graphics were not scaled.

I set the `LwjglApplicationConfiguration` config.width and config.height to 800 and 480. I tested it with different devices and resolutions, and the effect is still the same. I'm not doing anything in the resume() or resize() methods and I'm using the `OrthographicCamera` (`camera.setToOrtho(false, 800, 480)`);

What can I do to make this work correctly? It works perfectly for the desktop version by the way.

**EDIT: Relevant code parts:**

**AbstractBaseScreen.java**

```
public abstract class AbstractBaseScreen {

    // constants
    protected final int screenWidth = GlobalConstants.GAME_WIDTH; //800
    protected final int screenHeight = GlobalConstants.GAME_HEIGHT; //480

    // camera
    protected OrthographicCamera camera;

    // ui
    protected AbstractBaseInputHandler inputHandler;
    protected Skin skin;
    protected BitmapFont font;
    protected Background background;
    protected Texture backgroundTexture;
    protected SpriteBatch batch;
    protected Stage stage;

    public abstract void create();
    public abstract void resize(int width, int height);
    public abstract void update();
    public abstract void render();
    public abstract void pause();
    public abstract void resume();
    public abstract void dispose();
    public void onRender() {
        update();
        render();
    }
}
```

**Screen example: MainMenuScreen.java**
Displays two buttons and a background.

```
public class MainMenuScreen extends AbstractBaseScreen {
    // @Override
    public void create() {
        // set spritebatch
        batch = SpriteBatchSingleton.getInstance();

        // create stage
        stage = new Stage(screenWidth, screenHeight, false);
        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);

        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, screenWidth, screenHeight);

        // set skin
        skin = new Skin(Gdx.files.internal("data/ui.json"));

        // background
        background = new Background("backgrounds/bg_base");
        background.loadSprite();

        // buttons
        skillButton = new SkillButton(MainMenuScreen.class, skin);
        startButton = new StartButton(MainMenuScreen.class, skin);

        // add buttons to stage
        stage.addActor(skillButton.getButton());
        stage.addActor(startButton.getButton());
    }

    // @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);

        batch.begin();
        background.draw();
        batch.end();
        stage.draw();
    }

    // @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        stage.setViewport(width, height, false);
    }

    // @Override
    public void dispose() {
        stage.dispose();
        skin.dispose();
        skillButton.dispose();
        startButton.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {}

    @Override
    public void pause() {}

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        create();
    }
}
```

Comment: Two questions if you don't mind, 1)How are you testing 'resuming app' in desktop version. 2) Some code from resume, resize and show would help a bit.

Comment: I minimize and maximize the game window and set a breakpoint in the resume method.

Comment: post the relevant parts of your code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do anything on `resize()` .. Hope it will help :)

Comment: lol I thought you were really doing **nothing** on resize "I'm not doing anything in the resume() or resize() methods" @err